# Certain page element is not being fetched by PhantomJS and Selinium

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

So as I am trying to navigate different portions of NewEgg website. I got stuck at another step. If you visit [this link](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16826104328&RandomID=8406339484211620141105131308) you can see on right side `Shoprunner free 2-day shipping` once page is loaded. Screen is attached[image]

When I pick `Firefox` as a driver it works as it should but when I pick `PhantomJS` it does not `sign in` text under ShopRunner and instead of generate following page:

[image]

AS you can see, now **SHOPRUNNER** Logo along with text here.

I get following error from Selinium:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
NoSuchElementException: Message: u'{"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with link text \'sign in\'","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"95","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:52827","User-Agent":"Python-urllib/2.7"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\\"using\\": \\"link text\\", \\"sessionId\\": \\"f8ac9fc0-6b17-11e4-81d1-212ddc897fa8\\", \\"value\\": \\"sign in\\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/f8ac9fc0-6b17-11e4-81d1-212ddc897fa8/element"}}' ; Screenshot: available via screen
```

Code given below:

```
             from selenium import webdriver
             driver.get('http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16826104328&RandomID=8406339484211620141105131308')
            sleep(120)#this does not make any difference either.
            driver.save_screenshot('screen_aftersignin.png')
            driver.find_element_by_link_text('sign in').click()
```